# How I get a background location every n seconds?

Tags: codenameone

Is there any way to listen background location every n seconds? I need to get the location every 5 minutes to not drain the device battery.

PS I have a pro account.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new background locationlistener implemented recently, I haven't test it personally, but I believe it will help you.

There is blog about it [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html) and a sample usage could be found [here](https://gist.github.com/shannah/86c739edac34216d3c4d).

Although there's an [issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/f7PFb-39J6E/lm46ZYO6CwAJ) posted on codename one forum about it killing the app, but Steve mentioned he was working on fixing it.